# Join using an intermediary table in JPA (Need to order the final result by a column of intermediary table)

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, joincolumn

I am able to do a jointable using an intermediate table like below code:
Here is the keywords for a story

**In Story.java**

```
@ManyToMany(targetEntity=Keyword.class, 
             cascade={CascadeType.ALL, CascadeType.MERGE}, 
             fetch = FetchType.LAZY )
@JoinTable(name="STORY_KEYWORDS",
        joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="STORY_ID")},
        inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="KEYWORD_ID")}
)
private Set<Keyword> keywords = new HashSet<Keyword>(0)
```

**In Keyword.java**

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy="keywords")
private Set<Story> stories = new HashSet<Story>(0);
```

The tables are `story`, `keyword` and `story_keywords`.
Now I want the keywords to be sorted as per the "Weight" column of story_keywords table (intermediate table).
Please help.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I reformatted your code to make it more understandable but honestly, still can't figure out what you are asking. What is `Weight` column? What do you mean by `store as per weight column`? What error are you getting?

Comment: Weight column is a column from intermediate table(story_keywords). Here I am performing join of Story and Story_Keywords table to get the Keywords for a Story (Keyword is one of the table). Those keywords are  in the scattered order. Now I have added a column "Weight" to Story_keyword table (intermediate table) and want the keywords to be fetched as per the Weight column. I have googled it a  lot but didn't find any annotations which will allow me to specify an orderby criteria of intemediate table.

Comment: If your intermediate column has a column in addition to foreign key columns and you need that column, you will have to map that table to a Hibernate entity as well.

Comment: Thanks Ean, I have created an entity for that. However I have stuck at another place. The intermediary table has a composite key and I will need to perform a join with it. Can you please suggest.

Comment: Please post the code that you are stuck with.